# How to detect which swapchain is out of date?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I have multiple swapchains and one of them gets out of date.

```cpp
if (swapchain_count) {
    VkPresentInfoKHR present_info = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        swapchain_count,
        swapchain_array,
        swapchain_index_array,
        NULL,
    };

    vkQueuePresentKHR(queue, &present_info);
}
```

The `vkQueuePresentKHR` is returning `VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR`

**How do I determine which swapchain is out of date?**

> If I ignore the error returned by `vkQueuePresentKHR`,
> the next `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` of the swapchain in error will return `VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR`.
> And the following log is generated:

```
VUID-vkAcquireNextImageKHR-swapchain-01802(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 1050126472 - Validation Error:
[ VUID-vkAcquireNextImageKHR-swapchain-01802 ] Object 0:
handle = 0x948acd0000000008, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_KHR;
| MessageID = 0x3e97a888 | vkAcquireNextImageKHR:
Application has already previously acquired 1 image from swapchain.
Only 1 is available to be acquired using a timeout of UINT64_MAX
(given the swapchain has 2, and VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::minImageCount is 2).
The Vulkan spec states: If the number of currently acquired images is greater than the difference between
the number of images in swapchain and the value of VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::minImageCount as returned
by a call to vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilities2KHR with the surface used to create swapchain,
timeout must not be UINT64_MAX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [VkPresentInfoKHR](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkPresentInfoKHR) structure has a `pResults` field: if non-NULL, each entry in `pResults` will be set to the VkResult for presenting the swapchain corresponding to the same index in `pSwapchains`.

```cpp
// Provided by VK_KHR_swapchain
typedef struct VkPresentInfoKHR {
    VkStructureType          sType;
    const void*              pNext;
    uint32_t                 waitSemaphoreCount;
    const VkSemaphore*       pWaitSemaphores;
    uint32_t                 swapchainCount;
    const VkSwapchainKHR*    pSwapchains;
    const uint32_t*          pImageIndices;
    VkResult*                pResults;
} VkPresentInfoKHR;
```

In code you are setting `pResults` to `NULL`.

Try setting `pResults` to an array of `VkResult`.

```cpp
if (swapchain_count) {
    VkResult swapchain_result_array = new VkResult[swapchain_count];

    VkPresentInfoKHR present_info = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        swapchain_count,
        swapchain_array,
        swapchain_index_array,
        swapchain_result_array, // <-- the result array goes here
    };

    vkQueuePresentKHR(queue, &present_info);

    // handle the swapchain_result_array here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The swapchain that is out of date is the one you passed to the acquire call. Which *image* in the swapchain is out of date is simple: all of them. When a swapchain is out of date, all of the images in that chain can neither be acquired nor presented.

When a swapchain is out of date, you must create a new swapchain for the surface and then use that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to find which swapchain is out of data using `vkQueuePresentKHR`, but how ever you can do something like this, 
If the result of `vkQueuePresentKHR` is `VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR`, you can check each one of them using `vkGetSwapchainStatusKHR` and check which swapchain needs to be recreated.

And yes, this might be quite slow as you'll have to iterate through the whole swapchain array to find that one swapchain.

Another way is that the spec states: [Link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkResult.html)

> VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR A surface has changed in such a way that it is no longer compatible with the swapchain, and further presentation requests using the swapchain will fail. Applications must query the new surface properties and recreate their swapchain if they wish to continue presenting to the surface.

This means that you can track which surface (window) has changed and recreate its dependencies (the swapchain, possibly the physical device and logical device) and update the array before it throws that error.